# Set font-size for all elements with a specific font-family with pure css, no Javascript

Tags: css

Is there a way to use the font-family as a css-selector?

Like:

```
font-family:Arial{
   font-size: 16pt;
}
```

Achieved without any javascript, pure CSS. So far I doubt there is, but you never know.

Usecase:
Having a text in latin chars and thai chars with two different font-families has a bad styling when rendering pdf with e.g. Openhtmltopdf or displaying html in Internet Explorer. Chrome has some magic to make it look alright, but I dont want that. The thai font chars in my case can match the latin chars when setting them to 1.5em. So it would be great to have some selector that sets it to 1.5em when that font is used.

Comment: Just set all those values to body tag. font-size, font-family, color, line-height. That's how

Comment: Yes it does @AlonEitan . Some fonts in different languages have some strange dimensions.

Comment: @M4FI4S I am not sure you understood my question. I want to have elements that have the font-family set to XY have a specific relativ font-size.

Comment: Then this question is unclear. You need to create a [mcve] that demonstrate the issue

Comment: No, that is not possible. If the font-family was applied via inline `style` attribute _everywhere_, then you could perhaps use an attribute selector on that - but for styles originating elsewhere, no such selector exists.

Comment: Okay @04FS 
I think this would be a good answer to the question. Post it as an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to use the font-family as a css-selector?

No, that is not possible.

If the font-family was applied via inline `style` attribute *everywhere*, then you could perhaps use an attribute selector on that.

But for styles originating elsewhere, no such selector exists.

Comment: @Tanim had a way to achieve what I wanted with pure css. So it is possible after all.

Comment: Oh, I realized he used inline styling. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

`font` is the shorthand property for all 5 individual font properties and this is the order of how you use them-

- font-style
- font-variant
- font-weight
- font-size/line-height
- font-family

For example- `p {font: italic small-caps bold 12px/30px Georgia, serif;}`

And if you want a specific `font-family` and `font-size` for all the elements, you need to give these properties to the one `selector` that represents all the elements and that is `*` So the answer to your question is below-

```
* {font: 20px Arial, sans-serif;}
```

For more details [you can see this page](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font_shorthand.asp)

Answer (score 0):

**And if** you want to change or specify the `font-size` of an element that is set the `font-family` via inline CSS, **IT'S POSSIBLE**. **You can even change the** `font-famil`y **that is set via inline CSS**, see the snippet below, and **please lemme know** if it works for you or not.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Peddana&family=Sansita+Swashed:wght@600&display=swap');


*[style="font-family: 'Sansita Swashed', cursive;"] {
    font-family: 'Peddana', serif !important;
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<h2 style="font-family: 'Sansita Swashed', cursive;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
```

Comment: If the font-family is not set via inline, then you won't need this attribute selector. I thought that's the case in here.

Comment: @AnanasXpress So the elements that have the font-family set, it's not via inline CSS, it's set via external CSS ?

Answer (score -1):

```
body{
   font-family:Arial
   font-size: 16px;
}
```

**This your Answer**

this css apply the changes to your all text in your html file

---

Comment: That is not the question.